# Text nodes in XQuery

Tags: function, xquery, nodes

Creating a text node in XQuery is done like so

```
text { 'foo' }
```

Can someone explain the syntax here? Is a function being invoked? If so, I would expect to see `text('foo')`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a computed constructor; XQuery syntax for creating nodes. The same syntax works for creating (for example) elements and attributes:

```
element hello {
  attribute target { "world" }
}
```

See [The XQuery spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-computedConstructors) for full details.